# sliding a div from off right edge of screen with static div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, screen

I'm simply wanting a static button/image/div on a page which onclick activates a separate div to slide from the right side of the screen. This link is virtually what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/876/

The problem is, is that I don't want the button to slide with it, that should remain in a static position on the page. I'd then like a 'close' button within the newly visible div.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 45%;
    right:-280px;
    padding-left: 20px
}
#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
#slidecontent {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        Yar, there be dragonns herre!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to instead slide the content div. Something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/877/

Updated CSS:

```
#slidecontent {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
```

Updated JS:

```
$(function () {
$("#clickme").toggle(function () {
    $(this).siblings("#slidecontent").animate({right:'280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
}, function () {
    $(this).siblings("#slidecontent").animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
});
});
```